# GAWK in Win7 parsing a binary file

Tags: windows, awk, gawk

This works well in Linux:

```
awk '/QName\[[[[:digit:]]]/ { print $0 }' TRUCK.fsl > a.txt
```

I know there's changes you have to make under Windows but I'm stuck.

FYI the intent is to capture lines having entries containing `QName[1]`, `QName[18]`, etc. The file itself is binary but the code within it is presented as regular text and can be successfully extracted, under Linux anyway.

Comment: Since its a Windows question you might want to add a Windows tag but the usual advice would be to save the awk script in a file and execute it using awk -f to avoid the Windows quoting nigthmare.

Answer (score 0):

In windows it's better to create an awk dedicated file for the code, like this:

**script.awk**

```
/QName\[[0-9]+\]/
```

That's all, default action for matches is to print the line, so you don't need more code than that.

Now execute it like this in the command line:

```
awk -f .\script.awk TRUCK.fsl > a.txt
```

Put the awk script in the same folder as TRUCK.fsl, or specify full path for it.